# Drupal, where i can find footer file?

Tags: php, drupal

I need to put some code into the site on drupal and i need this code to work on every page of my site. How can i do this? I wanted to find the file of footer and put some code inside, but i can't find it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 3 ways to add **PHP** code in to the footer.

1> Turn on the [PHP filter](https://www.drupal.org/node/1046700) & enter the code into a block that is positioned in the footer left region.
2> Put the code in the appropriate **template file** in the sub-theme.
3> Make a **module** that outputs the code to a block; **activate and place the block**.

Suppose that you want to add following line to footer area :

```
&copy;<?php print date('Y');?> Your Company Name - Address of your company.
```

So best way to do it is make small module like this:

**copyright_block.info**

```
name = Copyright Block
description = Shows the (incrementing) current year and company information.
package = Other
core = 7.x
files[] = copyright_block.module
```

**copyright_block.module**

```
<?php
/**
* @file
* This module shows the copyright year and company information.
*/
/**
* Implements hook_help().
*/
function copyright_block_help($path, $arg) {
  if ($path == 'admin/help#copyright_block') {
    return t('Manually edit to change company information');
  }
}
/**
* Implements hook_block_info().
*/
function copyright_block_block_info() {
  $blocks = array();
  $blocks['show_copyright'] = array(
    'info' => t('Company Information'),
    'cache' => DRUPAL_NO_CACHE,
  );
  return $blocks;
}
/**
* Implements hook_block_view().
*/
function copyright_block_block_view($block_name = '') {
  if ($block_name == 'show_copyright') {
$content = "<p>&copy;" . date('Y') ." Your Company Name - Address of your company</p>";
    $block = array(
      'subject' => t('Company Information'),
      'content' => $content,
    );
    return $block;
  }
}
```

**NOTE:** Do not put **PHP end tag** `?>` at the end.

Comment: As I have mentioned in my answer, You can put that code in **template file** with the help of appropriate Drupal hooks.